# Calling other class function

Tags: c#, class, function, static

I have a `grid` class and a `MainWindow` class. Grid's class function needs to call MainWindow's function:

```
    // function from grid class:
    public Point functionFromGridClass()
    {
        Point variable = MainWindow.functionFromMainWindowClass(0, 0);
        // ...
    }
    // function from MainWindow class:
    public static Point functionFromMainWindowClass(int x, int y)
    {
        Vector2 mouse;
        mouse.X = x;
        mouse.Y = y + (ClientRectangle.Height - glview.Size.Height);
        // ...
    }
```

If I remove `static` keyword in `functionFromMainWindowClass`, then I can't call it from grid class. If I don't remove `static` keyword, then I can't use the MainWindow's class variables `ClientRectangle` and `glview`, I get a warning `"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"`. I've never faced this problem, what should be the solution?

Comment: I met this question almost every day, and at least every other day, :) why not do a search in stackoverflow?

Comment: I searched but didn't find, probably because I didn't know how to "name" this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid class has to hold a reference of an instance of the MainWindow and probably provided to grid upon construction.

```
public class GridClass
{
  private MainWindow window;
  public GridClass( MainWindow Window)
  {
     window = Window;
  }
  public Point functionFromGridClass()
  {
     Point variable = window.functionFromMainWindowClass(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I get a warning "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

The warning tells you what to do: you need an instance in order to call instance methods.

So you could remove the static keyword from the method and then in your Grid class create an instance of `MainWindow` in order to be able to call the method:

```
var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
var result = mainWindow.functionFromMainWindowClass(5, 6);
```

Comment: No, If I do that then ClientRectangle and glview variables won't be the same as original MainWindow's class(I really don't know how to explain). **I'm asking something about communicating between two classes.**

Comment: You haven't actually explained what `ClientRectangle` is so it is hard to help. But you could put this code in a helper class that you could instantiate whenever you need to call the method. Or reuse the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give specific advice without knowing exactly what is going on, but the general picture is that you need to somehow get the instance of the `MainWindow` class that you want to call the method on, either by passing it into `Grid` at construction or similar, or by getting it from some resource manager.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are called with reference of the className.
Call you Main window class function like this:

```
public Point functionFromGridClass()
{
     MainWindowClass.functionFromMainWindowClass(val1, val2);

}
```